# Abstract Factory Method and Polymorphism

Tags: design-patterns, abstraction, polymorphism

Being a PHP programmer for the last couple of years, I'm just starting to get into advanced programming styles and using polymorphic patterns. I was watching a video on polymorphism the other day, and the guy giving the lecture said that if at all possible, you should get rid of `if` statements in your code, and that a switch is almost always a sign that polymorphism is needed. At this point I was quite inspired and immediately went off to try out these new concepts, so I decided to make a small caching module using a factory method. ***Of course*** the very first thing I have to do is create a switch to decide what file encoding to choose. DANG!

```
class Main {
    public static function methodA($parameter='')
    {
        switch ($parameter)
        {
            case 'a':
                $object = new \name\space\object1();
                break;

            case 'b':
                $object = new \name\space\object2();
                break;

            case 'c':
                $object = new \name\space\object3();
                break;

            default:
                $object = new \name\space\object1();
        }

        return (sekretInterface $object);
    }
}
```

At this point I'm not really sure what to do. As far as I can tell, I either have to use a different pattern and have separate methods for each object instance, or accept that a switch is necessary to "switch" between them. What do you guys think?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126409/ways-to-eliminate-switch-in-code

Comment: Whoever you were listening to is spot on. Tons of ifs and switches in a code base are an immediate sign the authors don't think in OO.

Comment: For future reference, the video I was watching was this one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`switch` and `if` are generally required for primitives (which `$parameter` is), although PHP allows you to create class names and call methods from variables, so you can get away with a little magic.

For example you could do this:

```
public static function methodA($parameter = '') {
   $class = '\name\space\object' . $parameter;
   return new $class;
}
```

This of course requires that `$parameter` and the existing class names are all named appropriately, and it does not account for the default case.

The other alternative requires that `$parameter` be an object.  You can remove the switch, but it doesn't cut down on verbosity (although it is polymorphic).  One possible way:

```
public static function methodA(EncodingType $parameter = null) {
   return new $parameter->getObject();
}
```

...which would return the required object string.

I should note that the principle of avoiding conditionals in contemplation of using polymorphism is great, especially in theory -- but if you try to eliminate all conditionals in your code you can half kill yourself and end up writing unnecessarily complicated code.  It may also be a signal to rethink your design.

I will say that one common spot where you find conditionals is in factory methods, which is what your example seems to be.